# Sum Function with a where clause - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sum, where-clause

I need to run the following query, I know the below is incorrect but maybe this will give you an idea of what I output I need.

```
SELECT 
    [SchemeCd],          
    SUM([PayAmt] WHERE [ServiceMonth] = '201602'and [PayMonth] <> '') as [Feb-2016_P],
    SUM([PayAmt] WHERE [ServiceMonth] = '201603'and [PayMonth] <> '') as [Mar-2016_P]
INTO 
    [Claim Totals]
FROM 
    [All Claims]
GROUP BY 
    [SchemeCd]
```

Therefore I need to calculate the sum total of the Pay Amount for each specific service month whereby the Pay Month is not blank. I will then do another sum to calculate the sum total of the Pay Amount for each specific service month whereby the Pay Month IS blank.

**Original Table**

```
[PayAmt]|  [ServiceMonth]|  [PayMonth 

 500          201602         201602
 900          201602
 500          201602         201602 
 500          201603         201603
 600          201603       
 600          201603         201603
```

**Output - PayMonth <> '' (is not blank)**

```
[PayAmt]|  [ServiceMonth]|  [PayMonth  
 1000       201602           201602
 1100       201603           201603
```

**Output - PayMonth = ''(is blank)**

```
[PayAmt]|  [ServiceMonth]|  [PayMonth  
 900        201602           201602
 600        201603           201603
```

Comment: post some sample Data and output what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding,this should be your code

```
SELECT [SchemeCd],SUM(Case WHEN [ServiceMonth] = '201602'and [PayMonth] <> '' THEN [PayAmt] END) as [Feb-2016_P],
SUM(Case WHEN [ServiceMonth] = '201603'and [PayMonth] <> '' THEN [PayAmt] END) as [Mar-2016_P]

INTO [Claim Totals]
FROM [All Claims]
GROUP BY [SchemeCd]
```

Comment: I get the following error: Incorrect syntax near ')' - sorry no idea how to correct the syntax on the query.